# Multiple themes in plone.app.theming

Tags: themes, plone, diazo

I am trying to apply a different html (theme) to my front-page (index.html) while all my other pages will have the same theme (index_in.html). I am trying it this way and was wondering why it is not working:

excerpted from my rules.xml:

```
    ...
    <theme href="index_in.html" css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" />

    <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">

    <theme href="index.html" if-path="front-page"/>
    <theme href="index_in.html" />
    ...
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
<rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">
<theme href="index.html" if-path="front-page" />
<theme href="index_in.html" />
...
</rules>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the front page has #visual-portal-wrapper, then the first  will match that too and be used. Conditional themes are tried in the order they appear and the first one to match is used.

Comment: My generated html doesn't seem to include visual-portal-wrapper. How do I get it to appear? Should I base my theme on Sunburst?

Comment: You should probably include a rule that includes plone's body classes, which you can find at http://pigeonflight.blogspot.com/2011/11/common-diazo-rules-for-plone.html along with a number of other helpful hints.